# Webservice Integration PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have to integrate with a third-party webservice, they send us an example in VB.NET. I have no idea how could I do the same in PHP. I have the values of "URL_WS", "CERTIFICADO_WS" and "CONFIG_STRING"

VB.NET exemple:

```
Dim ServiceEndpoint = New EndpointAddress(New Uri(URL_WS),
EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(CERTIFICADO_WS)
Dim Binding = New WSHttpBinding()
Binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message
Binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName
Dim result = New Integracao.IintegracaoClient(Binding, ServiceEndpoint)
result.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None
result.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = CONFIG_STRING
result.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ""
```

Comment: If you have no idea, then start by reading the documentation of a PHP-based HTTP library such as cURL or Guzzle.

Comment: I would push back on the 3rd party support.  They should provide specs for integrating with their service.  They *can also* provide code samples for any given language.  But they should **not** assume that the client must be running a specific language/framework/environment/etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.